# Use XMPP to implement a push notification infrastructure

Tags: java, push-notification, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am currently working on a project which requires a server to request data from the devices which are currently connected to the server. Meaning, first the server finds out which devices are connected to the server and then sends an application specific message to the client device which should wake certain functionality present on the client.

I was looking into XMPP service which looked promising since it works as a PUSH notification. The  in XMPP can be used to check if the device is currently connected and has subscribed to the server. Since every android user has a gmail account, I was thinking of using the gmail xmpp service to connect /subscribe to the server. Then send specific message to the client, i.e x...@gmail.com.

However if a message is sent this way the client app gets the message as well as the native gtalk client. So how do I go about intercepting this so that it doesn't show up on the gtalk client but my app still gets it ?

Comment: XMPP "Push" doesn't necessarily make sense as XMPP is technically a connected protocol if you know what I mean. 

Have a look at setting up an XMPP server and playing around with that and the aSmack Library. 

It is hard to tell from your question if you have an easy way of obtaining which clients are connected or not or if that's what your asking? Are they connected to an XMPP service or some other web serivce/protocol? Have you implemented an XMPP sending service in your server?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full JID when sending the message. The send to multiple clients should only occur when the bare JID is used.

- Full JID  -> **xyz@gmail.com/device**
- Bare JID  -> **xyz@gmail.com**

Comment: the problem of using full JID is when the device is offline or for some reason the delivery fails the mesage is sent to the bare jid